Generalized variance for probability vectors
I am trying to compute something like the "generalized variance" for a bunch of probability vectors (vectors with non-negative entries which add up to 1). Let the vectors have length $n$. The "generalized variance" here refers to the determinant of the covariance matrix for the vectors, $\det(C)$,
$$ C = \operatorname{E}\left[(X - \mu)(X - \mu)^{\operatorname{T}}\right] $$
Unfortunately, since all such vectors live on the $(n-1)$-simplex, the covariance matrix is singular and the determinant is zero. While technically true, this is also not useful.
So, if I have a set of points on the $(n - 1)$-simplex, but embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what is a good way to compute the $(n-1)$-dimensional generalized variance (i.e., the multi-dimensional scatter on the simplex itself)?

Depending on how you will use your "generalized variance", there could be different ways to define such a generalization. For example, $\text{tr}(C)$ could also be thought as a measure of dispersion, which is not necessarily zero for a  singular $C$.

Unfortunately, the trace does not measure what I want. For example, if all the points are strongly correlated within the simplex, the trace will still be large because it ignores the off-diagonal covariances. The determinant is closer to the geometric interpretation I wanted, "what is roughly the volume captured by the points"

This is my attempt at asnwering my own question. I realized that one way of tackling this is to rotate the $(n-1)$-simplex in such a way that the last coordinate of each point is a constant (i.e., rotate the simplex to be perpendicular to the $n$th axis), and then drop that coordinate.
Let $e_n = (0, 0, ..., 1)^T$, an $n$-length vector, and
$$ \mu = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, ..., \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^T$$
is a unit-vector pointing towards the centroid of the $(n - 1)$-simplex.
We can define a Householder reflection using $v = (e_n - \mu)/\|e_n - \mu\|$,
$$A = I_n - 2vv^*$$
Applying this reflection to all vectors on the $(n - 1)$-simplex and then discarding the last coordinate seems to do the trick. I don't have a complete proof yet.
